# Is $(R;+,-,\times,<,=,\exp,0,1)$ decidable assuming Schanuel's conjecture? (note, there is $=$ too)

Tags: logic

A. J. Wilkie, in *Schanuel’s Conjecture and the Decidability of the Real Exponential Field*, says that $(R;+,-,\times,<,\exp,0,1)$ is decidable. What happens if equality is included too? That is, is $(R;+,-,\times,<,=, \exp,0,1)$ decidable or not?

There has been an earlier [thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134259/is-the-first-order-theory-with-of-real-numbers-with-addition-and-multiplicat) where the same question was asked but **without** the exponential, and the conclusion was that $(R;+,-,\times,<,=,0,1)$ is decidable. The confusion seems to come, I think, from the Wikipedia article, which says that the [Tarski-Seidenberg theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Seidenberg_theorem) ends up into problems with equalities.

Comment: Thanks a lot Noah; really appreciated. Just trying to understand: what goes wrong in the Tarski-Seidenberg Theorem as stated in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: I'm not sure what "wrongness" you're referring to. The wiki article mentions that the analogue of TS for algebraic sets - "the projection of an algebraic set is algebraic" - is false, but this isn't about *equality* but rather *inequality*. Note that equalities **are** allowed in the definition of a semialgebraic set.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says: ``If we only define sets using polynomial equations and not inequalities then we define algebraic sets rather than semialgebraic sets. For these sets the theorem fails.''  So, the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem is not true, in general, with Equality; is this a correct statement? I should say, I'm not particularly knowledgeable in the field of Mathematical Logic, so please bear with me if a question has an obvious answer or is non-sensical.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding the statement. A semialgebraic set *can* have equalities in its definition: it's allowed to use $=$, $<$, and $>$. An algebraic set is only allowed to use $=$. (See the new last part of my answer.)

Comment: I see. I think I understand, now, what you are saying. Many thanks Noah. Answers my question!

Comment: And Henning, what you write I think clarifies things further, maybe even drives the point home, for me. Thanks.

Comment: Re: Henning's comment, note that in general structures cannot define equality "after-the-fact." So the logical status of "$=$" is still very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality is included. In first-order logic, [equality is considered a logical primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Logical_symbols),$^*$ on the same level as quantifiers, Boolean operations, and variables. So the answer to your question is **yes**.

---

$^*$This was not always the case: historically, equality was not always considered a logical primitive (see e.g. the "lower predicate logic" of Robinson's book [Complete theories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/bookseries/0049237X/18)). However, it has become so, and e.g. when we speak about the theory of a structure equality is *always* included unless explicitly stated otherwise (and similarly, "the theory" means "the *first-order* theory" unless explicitly stated otherwise).

---

Re: the role of equality in the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem, I think there might be a misunderstanding. Briefly, TS states:

> The projection of a semialgebraic set is semialgebraic.

As wikipedia mentions, the natural analogue of TS for algebraic sets *fails*: there is a projection of an algebraic set which is not algebraic.

So: what's the difference between semialgebraic sets and algebraic sets? To quote from the wiki page, a semialgebraic set is one which is "a finite union of sets defined by a finite number of polynomial **equations** and inequalities." Note the word "equations" in there: that means that "$=$" *is* allowed in the definition of a semialgebraic set. An algebraic set, by contrast, is one which is a finite union of sets defined by polynomial equations (no inequalities allowed). So it's not that TS fails when *equality* is *included*, but rather when *inequality* is *excluded*.

Comment: And in any case $t=u$ is the same as $\neg(t<u\lor u<t)$ in this structure.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Quite right. But it's a point worth making in general.

Comment: And, to give an explicit example just for the record, the hyperbola $H: xy=1$ is an algebraic subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$. The vertical projection of $H$ onto the $x$-axis is the set $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ which is not an algebraic subset of $\Bbb{R}$.